# Why I gained 245 reputation points today?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-cap

If reputation points are capped at 200 per day, why I gained 245 today?

https://superuser.com/users/170331/sekhemty?tab=reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepts (the green check marks worth 15 reputation) and bounties are exempt from the reputation limit. You got three of those today, worth 45 reputation.

Note that they do count towards the limit, i.e. if you get them early, they'll cause regular votes to not increase your reputation.

See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, it was also in the FAQ but I realized it just now...

Comment: Wait I'm a little confused... if I've hit my limit and accept an answer does the rep from that not apply?

Comment: @KronoS I guess it's also considered an 'accept' for the purposes of limiting rep, and not counting it would just lead to strategic accepting scheduling, but I'm not sure.

Comment: That's what I thought, but was a little confused by your "if you get them eartly" statement.  I thought the only thing that didn't count towards daily rep was bounties.